# How can I prevent a grid layout div from overflowing the viewport?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I have 2 divs inside my grid. The first div can be small or very large, but should never grow over the screen size. The second div has a fixed size of 40px.

So the first div should be either

1. Screen size - 40px
2. Size of the content (if smaller than 1.)

Content that exceeds the `screen size - 40px` restriction will be visible with `overflow: scroll`.

```css
.outer__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 250px;
}

.content__one {
  width: 3000px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: red;
}

.content__two {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer__grid">
  <div class="content__one"></div>
  <div class="content__two"></div>
</div>
```

With this approach, the first div will never overflow, thus be 3000px wide.

I have created a simple JSFiddle to express my problem with code: https://jsfiddle.net/n9851dzm/7/

Comment: you can try by calculating the width using calc option in css
`.content__one {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: red;
}

.content__two {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}`

Comment: Are you opposed to using flexbox? I would suggest flexbox when aligning elements in 1 dimension.

Comment: Setting the first div to a fixed width is missleading since I don't think it reflects your real use case. But I'll do a wild guess and suggest you set `min-width: 0; min-height: 0` to that first grid item since I think it fix your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your html a little bit and rewrite the css according. Please check it out:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer__grid">
  <div class="content__one">
    <<div class="inner-content">Inner Content</div>
  </div>
    <div class="content__two">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 40px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.content__one {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.inner-content {
  width: 3000px;
}

.content__two {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using Flex to get your requirement

```
<div class="outer__grid">
  <div class="content__one">
  <div class="long__content"> </div>
  </div>
    <div class="content__two">

  </div>
</div>
```

and Following CSS,

```
.outer__grid {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.content__one {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content__two {
  width: 40;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  height:200px;

}

.long__content {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Checkout the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinishanto/wh7v9rjm/9/)